# When do I set the delegate property on a UINavigationController created by Storyboard?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uistoryboard

This used to be pretty straightforward in the good ol' xib days. I'm getting into custom transitions in iOS 7. The root view controller for the my app is a UINavigationController. To get custom transitions to work, I need to set the delegate on my main UINavigationController.

I'd like to do this as soon as possible after load time. I tried doing it in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but `self.window.rootViewController` is returning `nil` at that point.

So I guess my question is: **when is the earliest I can set the delegate?**

I suppose I can do it in `viewDidLoad` of my main view controller (the Navigation controller's root view controller), but that seems like the wrong place design-wise.

Comment: Can you link it in the storyboard?

Comment: The window's rootViewController property should not be nil in application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:. Are you sure you set the navigation controller to be the initial controller?